# How does Meteor allow client-side MongoDB queries to update the server?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How client can  able to execute MongoDB queries on the browser (client side), and how it's automatically update to server side? How DDP protocol work?

How the mongodb work from client side?

Comment: @Lukasz (I can't @-type your fancy username): can you provide any pointers as to why this question is unclear?

Comment: [You can't `@`-notify close voters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81855/) in any case, @Dan. The non-ASCII first letter is not an issue: if Łukasz was on the list of valid notification targets, [his name would pop up for tab completion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/). (You could also use copy-paste, of course.)

Comment: @Josh: fantastic :) So I have no recourse other than go to MSO and [draw ire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78533/150034)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: is [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78531/150034) incorrect then? It suggests @-mentioning each of the closers, and comes from a user with 22k rep on meta.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, it is indeed incorrect, as [the comment just below it points out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78529/how-do-we-get-the-attention-of-question-closers-to-re-open-a-question/78531#comment191434_78531), yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meteor runs a JavaScript-only version of Mongo in the client called Minimongo. It uses the **[DDP](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2012/03/21/introducing-ddp)** protocol to send back results to the server, which in turn writes them to the underlying MongoDB if [allow/deny](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) rules permit. You can read more about Minimong, DDP and reactivity at http://docs.meteor.com.

> Minimongo is essentially an in-memory, non-persistent implementation of Mongo in pure JavaScript. It serves as a local cache that stores just the subset of the database that this client is working with. Queries on the client (find) are served directly out of this cache, without talking to the server.

This [Quora answer from the Meteor CEO](https://www.quora.com/Meteor-web-framework/How-does-Meteors-Minimongo-work) explains how Minimongo works:

> Hi, I wrote (the first version of) Minimongo :) Yeah, it just uses JavaScript objects to represent Mongo documents, and I reimplemented the Mongo query and update $-operators in JavaScript (with a few exceptions as noted in the docs.) The hard part was figuring out the exact semantics of the operators, since the 10gen docs don't go into a lot of detail about edge cases. So I kept a Mongo shell open and would figure out how mongod handled each edge case, and then write a minimongo unit test to make sure it did the same thing.
>
> Besides the 10gen primitives, it also has code to keep a list of live queries against the database (Meteor's observe() API) and send add/remove/move/changes messages to keep the queries up to date. This amounts to inspecting the list of live queries whenever an object changes.
>
> [...]
>
> There is also some code to do database snapshots and restores, which is used to implement latency compensation (forking the database to apply a predicted change locally, and then rolling that back and replacing it with the official result from the server once it arrives.)

Comment: Means client can able to execute db query client side correct then how its secure

Comment: Security is handled by allow/deny rules - see http://docs.meteor.com/#allow

Comment: they are using  Node-fibers correct but its not working based on callback but nodejs main feature callback how it,s work

Comment: I'm sorry, I've given you a lot of information already but I'm having trouble understanding what you want. You need to learn a little more English.

Comment: Please check my answer again. I had edited it to include a link to DDP, the protocol used to communicate between the client and the server.

Comment: @MuruganPandian it communicates with the server to do it, it just looks like it is from the client but there is a lot happening that you don't see which is the same as it changing from the server